# Appengine Datastore Propery fromString () method

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a generic method to set a property in datastore entity instance from a string such that it carries out the underlying conversion based on the Property type.

```
person = Person ()
person.setattr("age", "26") # age is an IntegerProperty
person.setattr("dob", "1-Jan-2012",[format]) # dob is a Date Property
```

This is easy to write, but this is a very common use case and was wondering whether the Datastore Python API has any provision.

(Sorry if this is a pedestrian question, I am relatively new to Appengine and could not find thru the docs).

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I had a couple of days ago the same question for another usecase. To solve it I created a list of property types, to do the conversion I needed. This solution makes use of an undocumented db function and the internals of the db.Model class. Maybe there is a better solution.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
kind = 'Person'
models_module = { 'Person' : 'models'}       # module to import the model kind from

model_data_types = {}                        # create a dict of properties, like DateTimeProperty, IntegerProperty
__import__(models_module[kind], globals(), locals(), [kind], -1) 
model_class = db.class_for_kind(kind)        # not documented
for key in model_class._properties :         # the internals of the model_class object
    model_data_types[key] = model_class._properties[key].__class__.__name__
```

To convert your strings, you can create a class with string conversion functions like :

```
class StringConversions(object)

    def IntegerProperty(self, astring):

        return int(astring)     

    def DateTimeProperty(self, astring):

        # do the conversion here
        return ....
```

And use it like :

```
property_name = 'age'
astring = '26'

setattr(Person, property_name, getattr(StringConversions,  model_data_types[property_name] )(astring) )
```

**UPDATE:**

There is no documentation for :  `db.class_for_kind(kind)`
But there is better solution. Replace these two lines :

```
__import__(models_module[kind], globals(), locals(), [kind], -1) 
model_class = db.class_for_kind(kind)        # not documented
```

With :

```
module = __import__(models_module[kind], globals(), locals(), [kind], -1) 
model_class = getattr(module, kind)
```

Comment: That is interesting/useful feature to build a entity instance from name (db.class_for_kind)... My question is slightly different (sorry if not understanding your answer). I am interesting internalizing the attributes(properties fields) from string - as I mention in my question. I would like to always pass a string and have the function do the conversion to the python primitive type based on the property type (so if it an IntegerProperty then it would do an int(strArg) and then do a setattr () into the propery.. (Thanks nonetheless)

Comment: The resulting dictionary gives for a Model per property name the datatype of the properties. My usecase : a function to exchange models (all the entities) between two GAE domains and / or zip the entities of a model. This function is used to convert datatypes like BlobReferenceProperty, BlobProperty and LinkProperty (with a get_serving_url). In your usecase you can convert the string to a property, where the conversion is controlled by the datatype for the property in the Result Model (Person).